# Remove default value of enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Would it be possible to remove the default value of an enum? I have the following:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: {
    auto_draft: 'auto_draft',
    draft: 'draft',
    future: 'future',
    pending: 'pending',
    private: 'private',
    publish: 'publish',
    trash: 'trash'
  }, _suffix: true
end
```

and the following in the post migration:

```
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE posts
        ADD status enum(
          'auto_draft',
          'draft',
          'future',
          'pending',
          'private',
          'publish',
          'trash'
        ) NOT NULL AFTER id;
    SQL
```

Right now if I create a post without passing the status, it will use `auto_draft`, which is the incorrect behavior: I would like to not have a default value. Would that be possible, and how to do it if the answer is yes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Rails migration to change the column null

`change_column_null :posts, :status, true`

This will take the table name, the column name, and set it to null true

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_null

I'm unfamiliar with that way of setting up an enum. I usually do

```
#not null column with default
add_column :posts, :status, :integer, default: 0, null: false

# for a nullable column...
add_column :posts, :status, :integer
```

And then in the model

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
...
  enum status: %i[...]
end
```